# Batch file with mkvmerge gives wrong output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm putting togheter a bat file, but I'm not sure if this is possible.
I'm trying to search all mkv files in a folder for embeded english subtitles and echo accordingly.
I get the `echo "%%a" doesn't have English subs.` no matter if there are english subs or not.
Is it possible or am I just wasting time?

```
for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
for /f %%b in ("C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix/mkvmerge.exe" -I "%%a" ^|  find /c /i "language:eng") do (
    if [%%b]==[1] (
        echo "%%a" has English subs.
    ) else (
        echo "%%a" doesn't have English subs.
        echo.
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
for /f %%b in ("C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix/mkvmerge.exe" -I "%%a" ^|  find /c /i "language:eng") do (
```

to

```
for /f %%b in ('"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -I "%%a" ^|  find /c /i "language:eng"') do (
```

(note that `"` is changed to `'`)

(note also - `\` is directory-separator; `/` is switch)

```
for /?
```

from the prompt for documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This turns out `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Comment: @Jon - a couple of `"`s were missing; I've added them back in.

Comment: @SomethingDark - Thanks you! Still same problem tho. As soon as I involve `'` it breaks. What am I missing? And why can't I use `mkvmerge` like I see in other scripts instead of giving full path to the program?

Comment: @Jon - What do you mean "it breaks"? Using `'` in `for /f ` loops is how you run commands through a for loop. That's the only way to do it. What error are you getting? Also, you can use mkvmerge by itself if you add `C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix` to the `%PATH%` system variable (do _NOT_ overwrite the variable!!!).

Comment: @SomethingDark - I get `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command` when I involve `'`. When I remove the `'` I get `"101.mkv" doesn't have English subs.`. But if it needs those, it maybe isn't running the program and simply jumps to the echo?

Comment: @Jon - That's exactly what it's doing. A `for /f ` loop where the thing inside the parentheses is surrounded by `"`s gets treated like a string. `echo %%b` to see what the value is. :)

Comment: @SomethingDark - Thanks for your patience. When I move the bat file to the mkvmerge folder, it works! But I wan't to execute it from temp folder, so I added `set mkvmerge=C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe` and changed `mkvmerge` to `%mkvmerge%`. Do I have to use PATH or why wont this work?

Comment: Got it, `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\` at the top and keep mkvmerge lines as is seems to do the trick! Thank you for your time @SomethingDark :)

Comment: How about using for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%b in (`"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -I ... Backticks instead of apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove space from path and use it i mean change folder name. keep it without any white space. there is something wrong mkvtoolnix library